Cannot update column value in R data.table
I have a data.table (let's call it mytable) that looks like below
A   B    C
v1  v2    p1, p2, p3, p1, p2, p2
v3  v4    p4, p5, p1, p2, p1
....

I want to convert it to below where I take only the unique values in column C for each row.
A   B    C
v1  v2    p1, p2, p3
v3  v4    p4, p5, p1, p2
...

When I try to take unique in the column, it gives me p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 in all rows.
I'm using the following code to get the data.table columns.
mytable[, .(A, B, paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(C, split=","))), collapse=", ") )] 
                              .


Above answers mimic what I commented yesterday below your deleted question. Why the deletion?

@Friede thank you for your comments and I replied to your comments. But the question was closed as some had later voted it to close it even after I added the code that I used. So stackoverflow suggested me to delete the question and ask a new one. Your comment reflects the code I have showed in the question, it didn't work. I had to use sapply as the answers suggest.

I said on each row, which is what sapply does here.

@Friede sorry but you did not say each row. You said - Then split on , , apply unique(), and paste together or use toString(). Thanks for the help anyway.

you need to apply the strsplit, unique, and paste functions row by row like this
library(data.table)

mytable[, C := sapply(strsplit(C, ","), function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=", "))]




You can try
> mytable[, C := sapply(strsplit(C, ", "), \(x) toString(unique(x)))][]
        A      B              C
   <char> <char>         <char>
1:     v1     v2     p1, p2, p3
2:     v3     v4 p4, p5, p1, p2

Data
structure(list(A = c("v1", "v3"), B = c("v2", "v4"), C = c("p1, p2, p3", 
"p4, p5, p1, p2")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table",
"data.frame"))


Thank you Thomas. I used the other answer which worked for me.
